# authorized_keys has my key, but it's still refused

Tags: ssh, authentication, public-key

I'm connecting from machine M1 to machine M2 using ssh (to the same user on the other machine). I should also mention the user shares the same key on both machines. With password authentication, everything works fine; not so with public-key authentication; I've ensured `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on M2 has the RSA key as authorized, but still - ssh falls back to password authentication. I get the following with `ssh -vvv`:

```
debug2: key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f42679e8200),
debug2: key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```

I should mention that I *am* able to connect using public-key authentication from other machines (not with the same key).

What are the potential reasons for key-based authentication failing in this case?

Note: The machines are both SLES (SuSE Linux Enterprise Server) 11.

Comment: Read the log file of the sshd. It should contain a clear reason why it rejects your ssh key.

Comment: You need to check the logs on the server to find out why this failed.

Comment: also double check the authorized_keys file content vis-a-vis the key your client is offering.  Run `ssh-keygen -l -f FILE` against each file, replacing FILE.  Output should be the same.  (If the authorized_keys file contains other keys it will have more lines but one of them should match the output of running this on your id_rsa.

Comment: @sitaram: Of course the key is there, otherwise this question wouldn't make sense...

Answer (score 3):

You were doing the right thing using `ssh -vvv` from the client, pair it with a sshd in debug mode, like this:

a second server instance:
`# /usr/sbin/sshd -p 1234 -dddd`

a dedicated client to connect:
`$ ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa-admuser admuser@server -p 1234 -vvvv`

In my case it turned out that the crucial info was printed on the client only.
The server went through

```
debug2: user_key_allowed: check options...
debug2: user_key_allowed: advance ...
debug2: key not found
```

while the client came up with this:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: .ssh/id_rsa-admuser RSA SHA256:<censored> explicit agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

So what was going on here?

The server was so old they could not negotiate a helper algorithm; the key was also *dated*, but generally fine.

What would be the basic approach now?

1. start dedicated server on a different port
2. connect from client in new session
3. compare the key exchange on both sides, step by step
4. validate findings using a newly generated second key pair

In this specific example there was a clear explanation that it was an insecure old method that had been deprecated, i.e. described here.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html

To be able to update that old box I could connect by adding `-o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` to the ssh command line on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Check the basics:

1. id_rsa and id_rsa.pub exist on both M1 and M2
2. id_rsa has permission 600 (i.e only the owner can read-write) on both M1 and M2
3. authorized_keys file has key pasted as a single line (no line break)
4. Permission of authorized_keys is 600
5. Typically, permission on my .ssh folder is 600 (default)
6. Check the permission of each folder /home all way up to .ssh
7. I know you want to use RSA, but try DSA key and see if it works. If it does, then we'll have zeroed in SSH and RSA config.

Answer (score -1):

The error you get is

```
/home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
```

Make sure this file exists, contains the private key that corresponds to the public key that you've added, belongs to `joeuser` and has `600` user permissions:

```
sudo chown joeuser /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa
sudo chmod 600 /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa
```

You should also try to explicitly define the private key like this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@remote.example.com
```

If you are not sure if this is the right key then I'd recommend to create a new RSA key pair

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

and add the content of the public key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the authorized_keys file of the remote server. Make sure that you don't overwrite an existing private key that you still need to login to other servers!

Comment: But I want to use the RSA key (which is the key I have): `Offering RSA public key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa` is that not good enough?

Comment: And does that file exist? Because the error message you get says it doesn't.

Comment: The RSA key file exists, but I've never created a DSA key file so obviously it doesn't.

Comment: Try to use ssh agent. You add ssh private key and use it for a log in. To chech if a agent has a key inside use `ssh-add -L `